# jsRender - How to show a message when there's no data to display

Tags: jsrender

Does anybody know if jsRender has something similar to the **[ASP.net EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** ???
I ask because I'd like to show a message in a html table, that was created using a template , when there is no data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `{{for}}` to loop over an array, you can use `{{else}}` for the case where the array is empty.

See http://www.jsviews.com/#fortag - in particular the section where the following example is shown:

```
{{for members}}
  <div>{{:name}}</div>
{{else}}
  <div>No members!</div>
{{/for}}
```